# cuda converting .png into grayscale

Tags: c++, c, cuda, png, grayscale

I'm writting app in c which can convert .png image into grayscale.
I'm using c and cuda. I have problem with cuda code and I don't know why. (I'm cuda begginer).

My transformation function looks:

```
__global__
void setPixelToGrayscale(unsigned char *image)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x*4;
    float gray;
    float r, g, b;
    r = image[i + 0];
    g = image[i + 1];
    b = image[i + 2];
    gray = .299f*r + .587f*g + .114f*b;
    image[i + 0] = gray;
    image[i + 1] = gray;
    image[i + 2] = gray;
    image[i + 3] = 255;
}


void transformToGrayCuda(rgb_image *img)
{

    unsigned char* image = img->image;
    unsigned char* image_d;
    unsigned width = img->width;
    unsigned height = img->height;
    int N = (int)width * (int)height; 
    size_t size = N * sizeof(unsigned char);
    cudaMalloc((void **) image_d, size);
    cudaMemcpy(image_d, image,  size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    setPixelToGrayscale<<<1, N>>>(image_d);
    cudaMemcpy(image, image_d, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(image_d);

/* this works fine if cuda code is commented
int j=0;
for(j=0; j<N; j++)
{
    int i = j*4;
    float gray;
    float r, g, b;
    r = image[i + 0];
    g = image[i + 1];
    b = image[i + 2];
    gray = .299f*r + .587f*g + .114f*b;
    image[i + 0] = gray;
    image[i + 1] = gray;
    image[i + 2] = gray;
    image[i + 3] = 255;
}
*/

}
```

I've done something wrong in cuda version because, when cuda code is commented and ill run in loop c code everything works fine. Why my cuda code doesn't work properly?

EDIT:
it's my test image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3yJu.png

it's my result with cuda: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzmWJ.png

it's my result with only c code: http://  [no space here, i have no rep]    i.imgur.com/lU4vIiK.png

that's what i meant when i wrote that my cuda code does not work properly.

Comment: Impossible to say without a complete example someone else could run.

Comment: http://sh.st/wFY2T
here's link to my code

Comment: Lol, I have no intention of watching a video ad just to see your source code.  Why not edit it into the question? (or at least use pastebin.com or similar)  Anyway, post a complete code *in your question*.  Also, put [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) into your code.  And run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is:

```
cudaMalloc((void **) image_d, size);
```

You should give a pointer to the pointer, not cast the variable it to.
The right code is:

```
cudaMalloc(&image_d, size);
```

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: Weighted average is correct.  The numbers OP used are the NTSC weights.  In sRGB, the weights are Y = 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B.  Both sets of weights account for the human eye being more sensitive to green and less sensitive to blue.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson In the first revision he said the image wasn't looking proper. Another WTF is: I got a downvote being the right answer. (The user wrote the answer in the other answer's comments and chose the other post to be the right answer)

Comment: I downvoted because of the suggestion to use unweighted average of colors.  See http://www.poynton.com/notes/colour_and_gamma/ColorFAQ.html#RTFToC9 which explains why the values should be weighted.

Comment: Incorrect statement about weighting has been removed from the answer, so +1.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Monitor shouldn't weight the colors itself to our eyes' color like that camera captures frames that looks like how we see the world too? Thanks btw.

Answer (score 2):

What is the size of N?. You are running all N threads in a single block. There is a limit of 512 or 1024 threads per block depending upon the GPU. Please change the number of blocks if N > 512. With nummber of blocks = 1 + N/ 512 and threads per block = 512. Here, you need to check in kernel if threadid < N to avoid accessing out-of-bounds memory.

Also, kernel executions are async. So, you need a cudadevicesynchronize() call after kernel invocation.

If you give exact error/ issue you are getting then I can provide more help.

Comment: cudaMemcpy and cudaFree are both blocking calls. An explicit synchronisation call is not required in this case.

Comment: I changed it, but it still doenst change image to grayscale.
I uploaded my code in comment to main post, can you check it?

Comment: There is a race condition in your code. image[i + 2] for ith thread and image[i + 1] in (i + 1)th thread are going to write at same location possibly at the same time. Race conditions cause unpredictable results. Please refactor your code for this. I believe that would not be much difficult for your code's logic.

Comment: Also, check if the size variable fits within 'int' range. Sometime, the 'int' range might not be able to accommodate and you need to use 'long' in such cases.

Comment: Yeah, but i = threadID * 4, so its ith thread needs access to image[i*4] : image[i*4 +3]

Comment: And my N in this case is 128*128

Comment: even if i = threadid*4, it would result in race condition as (i+2) and (i+1) of consecutively numbered threads would point to same element.

Comment: Well, no, (4+2) != (8+1). I found the problem.
In cudaMalloc((void **) image_d, size); I had to use pointer to image_d, not image_d
Your advaices about blocks was usefull. Thanks